# Csrf token not set on Express when redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, csrf

I'm using the `csrf` middleware with the *Express* framework. My *login* page is like this:

```
app.get('/', getUserOrLogin, function (req, res) {
  // do something...
});
```

Where the `getUserOrLogin` is:

```
// Return the user otherwise redirect to login page
var getUserOrLogin = function (req, res, next) {
  var user = req.session.user;

  if (user == null) {
    req.session.backTo = req.originalUrl; 
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    req.user = user;
    next();
  }
};
```

When I try to access `/` it redirects me correctly to `/login` but the `csrf` token in cookies is not set.

Am I doing something wrong with the `getUserOrLogin` function or is an Express bug?

Comment: What happens if you assign the backTo value to the *response* object rather than the *request* object ?

Comment: Is the csrf middleware defined before the router?  Also, when you say cookies do you mean session?  Unless you're doing something else, csrf doesn't set a cookie, just the `_csrf` session token.  Thirdly, what are you using for auth, and what does the login route look like?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. Since I don't want `csrf` control on every page I was using a conditional function:

```
// Disable CSRF for some requests
var conditionalCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
  var whitelist = ['/inbound'];

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    next();
    return;
  }
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.url) !== -1) {
    next();
  } else {
    (express.csrf())(req, res, next);
  }
};

app.use(conditionalCSRF);
```

But that function doesn't set the `csrf` token until the user requires a page that requires it. So I modified it in that way

```
var connect = require('connect');

// Disable CSRF for some requests
var conditionalCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
  var whitelist = ['/inbound'];

  req.session._csrf || (req.session._csrf = connect.utils.uid(24));

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    next();
    return;
  }
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.url) !== -1) {
    next();
  } else {
    (express.csrf())(req, res, next);
  }
};

app.use(conditionalCSRF);
```